# ASP.NET Core MVC Product Database with Multiple Prices

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am upgrading one of my sites from WebForms to MVC Core. Would you please give me some advice on how to create their database? Here is some example code from the .VB file behind the [Rabbit Bikes Products](http://rabbitbike.com/Products) page. It is VERY messy because a lot of their products have two or more prices.

```
For Each prod As Product In myProducts
        'Beginning Layout
        temp &= "<article class=""dbItem""><figure class=""left dbImage"">"

        temp &= "<img src=""" & prod.ImagePath & """ alt=""" & prod.Name & """ title=""" & prod.Name & """ style=""width: 100%;"" class=""pull-left img-rounded""></figure>"
        temp &= "<h2>" & prod.Name & "</h2>"
        temp &= "<div class="" scroller""><p>" & prod.Description & "</p></div>"
        If Not prod.Description.Contains("shuttle") And Not prod.Name = "Trail Pass" Then
            temp &= "<h3 style=""text-transform: uppercase;"">Call to reserve yours today!</h3>"
        Else
            temp &= "<h3 style=""text-transform: uppercase;"">Call to purchase one today!</h3>"
        End If
        temp &= "<br /><div style=""text-align: center;"">"
        If prod.Description.Contains("shuttle") Or prod.Description.Contains("frequent rider") Then
            temp &= "<span class=""oSnap"">One Person:</span> " & prod.TwoHrPrice.ToString("c") & "<br/>"
            temp &= "<span class=""oSnap"">2 or More <abbr title=""people"">ppl.</abbr>:</span> " & prod.FourHrPrice.ToString("c") & "</p>"
        End If
        If prod.TwoHrPrice = 0 And Not prod.Description.Contains("shuttle") Then
            temp &= "<p>Free with purchase!</p>"
        End If
        If prod.FourHrPrice <> 0 And Not prod.Description.Contains("shuttle") And Not prod.Description.Contains("frequent rider") Then
            temp &= "<p><span class=""oSnap"">Half Day Price:</span> " & prod.FourHrPrice.ToString("c") & "<br/>"
        End If
        If prod.OneDayPrice <> 0 And Not prod.Description.Contains("shuttle") Then
            temp &= "<span class=""oSnap"">One Day Price:</span> " & prod.OneDayPrice.ToString("c") & "<br/>"
        End If
        If prod.TwoDayPrice <> 0 And Not prod.Description.Contains("shuttle") Then
            temp &= "<span class=""oSnap"">Two Day Price:</span> " & prod.TwoDayPrice.ToString("c") & "<br/>"
        End If
        If prod.WeekPrice <> 0 And Not prod.Description.Contains("shuttle") Then
            temp &= "<span class=""oSnap"">Week Price:</span> " & prod.WeekPrice.ToString("c") & "</p>"
        End If

        'End Layout
        temp &= "</div></article>"
    Next
```

Since switching to ASP.NET Core 1.1 and the Entity Framework, I've been trying to figure out how to check the number of prices for each item and labeling them appropriately. I tried using arrays, but they won't work because each variable type in an Entity Framework Model class is connected to a SQL Server data type. I don't want to use a bunch of if/else statements to count how many prices are associated with each product and label them appropriately again. My Product class isn't that different from the one in ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework and CSS.

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Product Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string PriceLabels { get; set; }
    public decimal Prices { get; set; }
    //Add a third table to hold price information?
    //public int? PriceTableID { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Category Name")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

I would appreciate any insight you might have about this issue.

Answer (score 2):

What is your question exactly?  Generic "advice" is off topic here.  You should ask a specific question to get specific answers.  If your question is how you count prices, you simply do a query and use the count method linq.  for instance, assuming your database context is called db, and your products table is Products.

```
var count = db.Products.Where(x => x.ProductId == yourproductid).Count();
```

In this scenario, you would have multiple entries for each product/price combination.  Another option would be to create a one-to-many of product to prices, and then you would query the prices separately.

This is really basic Linq functionality, and you seem to be very inexperienced, so I suggest reading some tutorials on entity framework.  EntityFramework core is quite a bit different in specifics, but generally works the same as far as queries are concerned as traditional entity framework.

Comment: I was thinking something similar; create a Prices table that holds the label and price for that product, and then link the two tables with a reference to the Product table and another reference to the Price ID in the Prices table.

` //Add a third table to hold price information?`
` //public int? PriceTableID { get; set; }`

Since there are multiple prices, would I need to add this line, too?

`public virtual Category Category { get; set; }`